# Need to go to Brazil but Brazilian passport is expired

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, dual-nationality, brazil

I need to go to Brazil on December 7th but just found out my Brazilian passport is expired. I have dual citizenship: Brazil and US. My US passport is valid. I have tried to schedule an appointment at the Brazilian consulate in Miami to renew my passport but the earliest date available is December 19th so that will not work. Would I be able to enter Brazil with my expired Brazilian passport and then re-enter the US with my valid US passport? Help, trying to figure this out ASAP!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by check-in staff at airports:

> Nationals of Brazil are allowed to enter with an expired
>     passport.

So your expired Brazilian passport is absolutely enough, and if check-in staff doesn't know this, tell them to check Timatic.

A valid Brazilian *carteira de identidade* is another option (listed in Timatic as well)

Comment: Even if the don’t check, how many airline personal would be foolish enough to think that your own country won’t let you in?

Comment: @WGroleau Many countries do require their own documents to be valid on arrival, and while they'd let you in, they could heavily fine the carrier and, depending on the country, also the passenger.

Comment: Well, true, one must never count on common sense from bureaucrats.  "We can't keep you out, but we can certainly make sure the airline won't help you get in."

Comment: @WGroleau Most countries will accept you to get back even with a expired passport but no because it makes your life easier. They do it because instead they need to pay for the logistics and personnel to issue and stamp it at each consulate (more work for the bureucrats)

Comment: @Crazydre [citation needed]. I can't recall any country fining you for entering on an expired passport. Indeed, that doesn't sound plausible as they are obligated by international law to let you in if you can prove your citizenship in any way.

Comment: @chx It's perfectly possible; it may well be the law that passports, even of the country's nationals, must be unexpired for both exit and re-entry. Violating that can thus NOT lead to entry being refused, but CAN lead to fines (for pax and carrier). Boils down to the country's laws really.

Answer (score 2):

You can travel BACK to Brazil with an expired passport. Note that you do not need a valid passport to enter your own country. You simply need to prove identity and citizenship, which even an expired passport will do. That said, you are likely to experience an extended interview and delay upon returning.

Answer (score -1):

You can enter with your expired passport as long as you have another document made in Brazil with photo.
This document can be RG (identidade) or carteira de motorista.

Comment: Can you give us a link to an official site where it is written that you need a secondary Brazilian document? This is other than the (now older) answer.